# Do Variables save when the form closes?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, variables

Take this example:

I have a `LoginForm` and when I enter my credentials into the text box and click *Go* it the directs me to my main `HomeForm`. On this event it stores the current user text from the User `Textbox` in the Login form in a `Public Variable` in the `HomeForm` called *CurrentUser*  So my code is like this:

```
Private Sub OK_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles OK.Click
Home.CurrentUser = UsernameTextBox.text
End Sub
```

When I then try to access the information stored in the variable I am having no problems it's just that I want to know if the user closes the `HomeForm` will the variable still equal to the previous value before the user closed the Form. And if not how would you recommend on saving. I Don't want to be using stream readers/writers due to all the unnecessary text files.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you declare CurrentUser as **Shared** then it will keep the value even when the form is closed and then re-opened (assuming the whole application hasn't been closed):

```
Public Class HomeForm

    Public Shared CurrentUser As String

End Class
```

Access it using the Forms name:

```
Private Sub OK_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles OK.Click
    HomeForm.CurrentUser = UsernameTextBox.text
End Sub
```

*If you are looking at saving this value across application runs, then add a "CurrentUser" value in Project --> Properties --> Settings, then use code like:

```
Private Sub btnOK_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnOK.Click
    My.Settings.CurrentUser = UsernameTextBox.text
    My.Settings.Save()
End Sub
```

You can retrieve the value from anywhere using: `My.Settings.CurrentUser`

Comment: `CurrentUser` will keep its value even when it is *not* `Shared`, as long as the same `HomeForm` instance is accessed.

Comment: You should really understand the implications of shared objects before using them. They work similarly to globals and are rarely a good place for storing information.

Comment: Agreed; as long as you access the **same** instance.  The **Shared** approach will work even if that instance is disposed.  It also gives a nice _global_ variable that can be accessed from **anywhere** without the need to pass a reference around.  It all just depends on how you plan on using that value I suppose...  =)

Comment: If there is only ONE "current user" at any given time, then a global/shared member is perfectly valid.  That is what they are intended for; a way to hold something that is common across an entire application, and only needs to store that one thing at any time.  If you need to store a different "current user" associated with multiple _things_, then a global is not the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

As long as you access the same instance of your `HomeForm` class, the variable values will still be there for you to access after the user has closed the form.

This applies to any fields or properties that do not access any of the inherited properties or methods of the `Form` class. Such methods by `Form` may depend on internal resources that are indeed freed upon closing or disposing of the form, while simple CLR properties will remain untouched for as long as the instance is within scope.

Comment: Would the downvoter mind to explain what was the reason for the downvote?

Comment: Sorry, thinking to hard about the answer and this question. It assumes the scope of HomeForm is always available or global. Regardless your answer makes sense for the question. It won't let me upvote unless you put an edit there.

Comment: Anyway you can put a space or something in your answer, so I an change it to an upvote?

Comment: When the form is closed, the instance is killed, isn't it? I mean it's forced to Dispose, and hence you cannot rely on variable availability, right?

Comment: @Neolisk: Not at all. It just means that some underlying unmanaged resources such as window handles are killed. CLR properties that just store managed values and that do not rely on any of the unmanaged resources will keep working as usual; nothing happens to the managed instance itself. UNLESS, that is, someone has explicitly implemented some code that checks whether the object has been disposed of and throws an exception when a property is accessed for a disposed instance. Obviously, that's never the case with mere fields.

Comment: @Neolisk: For further information, have a look at [the accepted answer on this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7456953/why-disposed-object-doesnt-throw-exception-on-using-it-after-disposing), which starts with the memorable quote "Disposed doesn't mean gone." This is confirmed by what I can see in `Form`/`Control`.`Dispose` in ILSpy.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim onearray() As String
Dim i As Integer
Private Sub OK_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles OK.Click
Home.CurrentUser = UsernameTextBox.text
Home.CurrentUser = onearray(i)
i = i + 1
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you are calling your form from the login form you described. Calling it with the show method will dispose the form after the user closes the form. Please see comments below for explanations and behavior this may cause.

According to MSDN
[The Closing event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.closing%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) occurs as the form is being closed. When a form is closed, all resources created within the object are released and the form is disposed.

Based on further examination it is possible to read a simple variable even if the form is disposed. However, in my opinion I would approach saving the needed data by passing in an object or variable as outlined below.

There are several ways you can persist or save the Current User information in order to safely access it later. Here is one.

1. Create a class called CurrentUser and give it basic public properties you can get and set.
2. Add a New Constructor to HomeForm and pass a byref argument reference of the new CurrentUser object.
3. Set or get any information needed from the CurrentUser object
4. When the form closes you will have the information needed from the CurrentUser object passed into the form. Ensure the scope of this object is avaliable to other parts of your as needed. (i.e make it a public property in the form that calls the Home form.)

   ```
   dim ouser as new CurrentUser 
   dim frmHomeForm as new HomeForm(ouser)
   frmHomeForm.show 
   msgbox(ouser.Name)
   ```

If you want to save the value after the user closes the application then you can add a setting in the Project Properties, and just refer to My.Settings.YourSettingName instead of using a variable to get and set the users login name.

Comment: All this is wrong. When a form is closed it is not released and not disposed. All the properties are available until the form is disposed, which will happen at a random moment given the code in this answer. Which is why you use `Using` when working with forms to control the moment of disposing: `Using f As New LoginForm: f.ShowDialog(): MsgBox(f.AProperty): End Using`. `AProperty` is accessible despite the form has closed.

Comment: @GSerg: Even after the form has been disposed (by using the `Dispose` method), custom properties or fields like the `CurrentUser` field from the question will retain their values.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Technically yes, though in reality they stop working because more often than not they examine properties of the form controls that now throw `DisposedException`.

Comment: @GSerg: Mere *fields* will certainly not examine anything else. Properties might indeed fail due to `DisposedException`s, but then, the question specifically refers to properties that simply just remember some additional information.

Comment: So I go from having my answered marked as accepted and up 1 to down -1? Microsoft's own documentation states "When a form is closed, all resources created within the object are released and the form is disposed." Are we really suggesting that the answer is to use a shared property?

Comment: MSDN unfortunately contains too many wrong/vague things these days. What you are saying applies to forms shown non-modally, they are disposed automatically upon closing (I didn't know that!). This does not happen to forms shown modally. But either way, even a disposed form is perfectly usable in the terms of retreiving its custom (and some non-custom) properties as @O.R.Mapper said. So yes, you are correct that `Dispose` is called for forms shown with `Show` (but not `ShowDialog`), but the answer remains wrong because disposing does not mean finalization/destruction.

Comment: As for the shared property, it is not the answer. As @O.R.Mapper noted in his comment, `Shared` is not required.

Comment: @SoftwareCarpenter: Try it for yourself. Nothing prevents you from accessing the fields that you store in your form class after the form has been closed. What *is* released is GUI-related resources for the internal Win API GUI stuff, but that does not influence any of your custom fields. And, no, not even a `Shared` property is required, a totally normal property will do, as the managed object instance will remain in existence for as long as it is within code scope.

Comment: The OP does not state how he is calling his form and in which scope his form is created. Therefore I answered his question which included recommendations on how to save variables. I am not incorrect depending on how the code is setup. He also asks will the variable still equal to the previous value before the user closed the Form-- implies the value is being changed or not being changed at all. I think you could lighten up a little bit and stop taking points away without thinking about the complete answer given.

Comment: It is a disposed object and therefore cannot be guaranteed what value will exist. I don't see how this is an answer for saving variables!

Comment: @SoftwareCarpenter I'm happy to remove my downvote but I cannot until the answer is edited. It would be the best if you edited your answer to include explanations from the comments above.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Settings (Click Prject -> Project Settings -> settings -> Add setting) if you want to access it another time when you open your program variables might not save all the time only in case how you will use them.