# WeakReference to IDisposable

Tags: c#, winforms, weak-references

I have a class holding a WeakReference pointing to an object implmenting IDisposable.  After the object is disposed there is a period of time before it is garbage collected.  During that time the WeakReference can still be used.  This can result in unexpected behavior because we are now making calls against an object that has been disposed.

Does anyone have a suggested approach for dealing with this, checking the weak reference if the target has been disposed, etc.?

Background:
We have a WinForms application with a controller holding data.  Multiple UI controls may be presenting the data at any given time.  A form adds and removes the controls (and calls Dispose when it removes them) but is ignorant about what the controls are doing or what data they need.  Previously the controls would subscribe to events from the controller to receive notifications when the data was updated.  This results in memory leaks.  To address this the controller now keeps weak references to the controls, and notifies the ones that are still alive.

Comment: To be honest I don't understand the idea to explicitly and intentionally dispose an object and then try to resurrect it. The `WeakReference` applicability scenarios imply stochastic approach while your is not.

Comment: Each type should have well defined behavior after `Dispose` whether it has normal or weak reference (some guidance https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7456953/why-disposed-object-doesnt-throw-exception-on-using-it-after-disposing, or just regular `MemoryStream` as an example) - so it is unclear what "can result in unexpected behavior" you expect to see.

Comment: @DmytroMukalov There is no intentional attempt to resurrect anything.  It is the limbo between the object being disposed and the holder of the WeakReference recognizing it (after it gets garbage collected).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov You point out an issue elsewhere in project code.  Certain user controls in the project have not been written to have a well defined behavior after being disposed (that is another task to deal with).  Issues such as null references occur.  Perhaps that needs to be addressed at this point in time.

Comment: The problem is that once Dispose is invoked the WeakReference is useless as some important resources are reclaimed at this point.  So you either don't need a weak reference or don't need IDisposable here.

Answer (score 3):

Since `IDisposable` and `WeakReference` have mutual exclusive semantic you need to choose single one. Combining them is dangerous since after a disposal an object most likely will have inconsistent state which isn't suitable for a reusing. `IDisposable` implies that you'd like to control the life-cycle of your objects and aren't going to take back. It's like to put something into a dumpster and to say: "I'm done with this thing, now I don't care what happens with that". The `WeakReference` semantic is like to put something near a dumpster and say: "I'm gonna get back in 30 minutes or so, if noone puts this into this dumpster I'll take it back, but if it's inside I don't care".

Weak references imply that objects referenced by them don't have a long life that's they're good for quick memory reclaim but at the same time they give some chance to be reused so in your case you can rely exclusively on `WeakReference<T>`:

```
MyType instance;
if (weakRef.TryGetTarget(out instance))
{
    // resurrected, still can use it
}
else
{
   // object is collected, the new one should be created
}
```

Comment: Yes, you perfectly describe the situation I am dealing with.  I'm not sure about your exclusively use WeakReference however as the objects being dealt with implement IDisposable.

Comment: @denver, Again you need to choose single approach.

Comment: The conflict is clear, but they are serving two different purposes, so there is not single approach.  A different design pattern other than using WeakReferences may be needed to support the notifications.  Or I could cheat and provide a way to check if an object is Disposed.

Comment: @denver It can be tricky to check if an object is disposed because you'll have ensure thread safety in case if someone else calls `Dispose` at the moment when you check.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone else stumbles across this question they way I resolved it was to make the referenced objects have well defined behavior after being disposed (per the comment by Alexei Levenkov).  The easiest way to do this was to ignore function calls after the object had been disposed.

```
public void OnDataChanged(object model)
{
    if (IsDisposed)
    {
        return;
    }
    ...
    // method implementation
}
```

This was only necessary in the single function being called from the weak reference.

Multi-threading was not an issue as these are UI objects and Invoke and BeginInvoke were already required to make calls modifying them.